# Android Studio library project reference unresolved symbols

Tags: android, gradle

I'm finally migrating my eclipse android projects to Android Studio. I've created a Project which contains two modules. One module is an library project. The other is plain Activity Project which includes the library module.

```
Project/
   app/     (Activity Project)
   br_lib/  (Library Project)
```

In the apps 'module settings' i added an [dependency](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1hkOb.png) to the lib module.
The lib modules project builds normally, but my app modules build fails everytime i make a reference to one of the lib modules Classes:

```
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.cddevlib.breathe.setup.Utils <--  // lib refrence;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Utils.convertName(""); // <--- lib module static class;
    }
}
```

Errors:

```
Error:(9, 34) error: cannot find symbol class Utils
Error:(25, 9) error: cannot find symbol variable Utils
```

What is wrong? What am i missing? Thank you

This is the app modules gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "pro.breathe.cddev.org.br_gold"
    minSdkVersion 22
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),     'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':br_lib')
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar']) 
}
```

This is the lib modules gradle:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
android {
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 9
    targetSdkVersion 9
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.0'
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles 'proguard.cfg'
      }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

This is the projects gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
    jcenter()
    }
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
}
```

settings gradle is:

```
include ':app', ':br_lib'
```

Comment: Compile files location incorrect

Comment: Post your settings.gradle and dont'use an absolute path with your jar files.
Also you are using different version of support libraries.

Comment: Yes yes.I assume it's your location fault. Am I right sir Gabriele

Comment: Ive updated my compiles file location but still get errors when accessing classes of lib module in my app module

Answer (score 2):

Ran into the same issue today in a project with 5 modules (2 of which are `com.android.library` modules). After lots of trial and error changes to my build.gradle file, the solution ended up relating to including the `publishNonDefault true` attribute in the library module's gradle file.

I found this post to be very helpful:
[StackOverflow - Product Flavors and Library Publication](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33195970/2329326)

My Application gradle file ended up looking like (code intentionally omitted):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.2'

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    }

    defaultConfig {
    }

    productFlavors {
        funapp {
            applicationId "com.funapp.package"
        }
        funappbeta {
            applicationId "com.funapp.beta"
        }
    }

    signingConfigs {
        googleplay {
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            debuggable true
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
        release {
            debuggable false
            signingConfig signingConfigs.googleplay
        }
    }
}

configurations {
    funappDebugCompile
    funappReleaseCompile
    funappbetaDebugCompile
    funappbetaReleaseCompile

    // Establish debug compile dependencies for build variants
    [funappDebugCompile, funappbetaDebugCompile].each {
        it.extendsFrom commonFunSdkDebugCompile
    }
    // Establish release compile dependencies for build variants
    [funappReleaseCompile, funappbetaReleaseCompile].each {
        it.extendsFrom commonFunSdkReleaseCompile
    }
    // Common Android and JUnit testing dependencies (JUnit tests can be run
    // using only a JVM; Android tests require a device or emulator)
    [androidTestCompile, testCompile].each {
        it.extendsFrom commonTestCompile
    }
}

dependencies {
    commonFunSdkDebugCompile project   (path: ':fun-sdk', configuration: 'debug')
    commonFunSdkReleaseCompile project (path: ':fun-sdk', configuration: 'release')
```

And my Library gradle file looks like:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.2'

    publishNonDefault true // <-- This happened to be the key component
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    }

    defaultConfig {
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
        }
        release {
        }
    }
}

configurations {
    debug
    release
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
```