# Add productFlavor to experimental Android gradle plugin library

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, gradle-experimental

I've got a project that uses the experimental gradle plugin, i.e. `0.2.0`. When I've got no `productFlavor`, I can perfectly integrate a library module in Android Studio and everything works perfectly. But when the library has a `productFlavor`, I main project doesn't find the library classes.

This [fix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24860659/multi-flavor-app-based-on-multi-flavor-library-in-android-gradle) does not appear to work with the experimental gradle plugin. Does anyone have any idea how make flavors work with the new plugin?

Library:

```
android.productFlavor {
    create ('flavor') {
        ...
    }
}
```

Project:

```
...

dependencies {
    compile project(':mylibrary')
}
```

Answer (score 10):

This might help?

> **Library Publication**
>
> By default a library only publishes its release variant. This variant
>   will be used by all projects referencing the library, no matter which
>   variant they build themselves. This is a temporary limitation due to
>   Gradle limitations that we are working towards removing.
>
> You can control which variant gets published with
>
> ```
> android { defaultPublishConfig "debug" }
> ```
>
> Note that this publishing configuration name references the full
>   variant name. Release and debug are only applicable when there are no
>   flavors. If you wanted to change the default published variant while
>   using flavors, you would write:
>
> ```
> android {defaultPublishConfig "flavor1Debug" }
> ```
>
> It is also possible to publish all variants of a library. We are
>   planning to allow this while using a normal project-to-project
>   dependency (like shown above), but this is not possible right now due
>   to limitations in Gradle (we are working toward fixing those as well).
>   Publishing of all variants are not enabled by default. To enable them:
>
> ```
> android {publishNonDefault true }
> ```
>
> It is important to realize that publishing multiple variants means
>   publishing multiple aar files, instead of a single aar containing
>   multiple variants. Each aar packaging contains a single variant.
>   Publishing a variant means making this aar available as an output
>   artifact of the Gradle project. This can then be used either when
>   publishing to a maven repository, or when another project creates a
>   dependency on the library project.
>
> Gradle has a concept of default" artifact. This is the one that is
>   used when writing:
>
> ```
> compile project(':libraries:lib2')
> ```
>
> To create a dependency on another published artifact, you need to
>   specify which one to use:
>
> ```
> dependencies {
>     flavor1Compile project(path: ':lib1', configuration: 'flavor1Release')
>     flavor2Compile project(path: ':lib1', configuration: 'flavor2Release') 
> }
> ```
>
> Important: Note that the published configuration is a full variant,
>   including the build type, and needs to be referenced as such. 
>   Important: When enabling publishing of non-default, the Maven
>   publishing plugin will publish these additional variants as extra
>   packages (with classifier). This means that this is not really
>   compatible with publishing to a maven repository. You should either
>   publish a single variant to a repository OR enable all config
>   publishing for inter-project dependencies.

From [here](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Referencing-a-Library).

Comment: I already tried [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24860659/multi-flavor-app-based-on-multi-flavor-library-in-android-gradle).

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is wrong.

With the experimental plugin (0.2.1) flavors are define outside the `android` block and the right syntax is `android.productFlavors`

```
model {
    android {

    }

    android.productFlavors {
        create("flavor") {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this example work for you on `0.2.1`? With the proper syntax, of course. `android.productFlavors` in the library and `compile project(':mylibrary')` in the main project.

Comment: The syntax is correct and it works fine with a application module. I don't know how it can work with a library. In my opinion you should move the flavor in the main module (I've never seen flavors inside a library)

Comment: The problem is that I have a library that contains some native C code. This C code uses a static library at link time which I need to specify in the `build.gradle` file. I need to do this for each architecture and the only way I know works is this: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/blob/master/hello-thirdparty/app/build.gradle

Comment: In the Known Limitations of official page you can find: No support for creating and depending on static libraries. Not sure if the issue can be related to this.

Comment: But it does work! They have their own *official* example. And I compiled mine and it works. What I need is just to be able to use this in a library.

Answer (score 0):

The things are a little bit more complex.
I've tested on gradle experimental 0.8.0

on the library you need:

```
model{
    android {
    ...
    publishNonDefault true

     productFlavors {
                create("flavor1") {
                }
                create("flavor2") {
                }
            }
    }
}
```

on the app you need:

```
model {
    android {
    ...
    publishNonDefault true

     productFlavors {
                create("flavor1") {
                }
                create("flavor2") {
                }
            }
    }
}
//after the model is closed !!
configurations {
    flavor1DebugCompile
    flavor1ReleaseCompile

    flavor2DebugCompile
    flavor2ReleaseCompile
}

dependencies {
...
 flavor1DebugCompile project(path: ':mylibrary', configuration: 'flavor1Debug')

flavor1ReleaseCompile project(path: ':mylibrary', configuration: 'flavor1Release')

 flavor2DebugCompile project(path: ':mylibrary', configuration: 'flavor2Debug')

flavor2ReleaseCompile project(path: ':mylibrary', configuration: 'flavor2Release')

  }
```

hopefully, if you run full assemble you will get 2 apk's, one for each flavor .
I've used "./gradlew build" from a cmd and got them.
note that for your lib, you will get an AAR for each flavor too